# Transfer Rate behavior of increasing request sizes

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket, apachebench

I've implemented a simple multi-threaded HTTP server for my programming assignment a couple weeks ago. In this assignment users specified a document size via browser (like localhost:port/250 for a 250 bytes long document) and my program created a html page with that size.

And I've tested it's performance with a benchmarking tool called apachebench. Performance was mostly what I've expected from a multi-threaded program.

But, there was an interesting test result which is bugging me for a while now.
The transfer rate of requests dramatically decreases with increased request sizes.
Here is my sample apachebench test results using this command line arguments;

ab -n 1000 http://localhost:port/RequestSize

```
RequestSize      TX 
(bytes)         (KB/s)
70              212,21
150             268,75
250             364,58
350             447,23
500             497,36
650             496,73
800             491,48
1000            432,63
1250            405,17
1750            347,19
3000            241,95
5000            161,46
10000           84,58
20000           44,05
```

the level of concurrency only makes this distribution less steep.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Thanks,

Comment: It would look like your transfer rate increases until you get around the size of a standard ethernet packet (1542 bytes), after which throughput starts dropping off.

Comment: That's was my first thought as well. I don't see why it would be a problem however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fairly easily narrow down where the delay is with some micro-benchmarks in the server. Beware, though, that micro-benchmarks may lead you down the wrong optimization path(s). You should at least be able to get a decent idea of where your time is spent, though.

If you are generating the payload on the fly, it may actually be the data generation which is becoming a problem at the larger sizes. The MTU on your loopback link should be much higher than the standard for LAN/WAN links (1500), so that shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it turns out that the data generation was causing this problem, when I tried to send a 20kb pre-generated file, throughput was much better.